# Stopping criteria when using the bisection method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, bisection

I'm working on old exams in basic numerical modeling.

The problem is:

$2x \ - e^{-x}=0 $ has a root in the interval $(0, 1.6)$. Find it with an error less than $0.02$ using the Bisection method.

The theoretical basis (copies from Rao's Numerical Methods) says $|f(x_{mid})| \le \epsilon $ is the stopping criterion, which gives $r = 0.35$ and $|f(0.35)|=0.0046880897$.

Theoretical basis:
[image]

[image]

The solution proposal says  $r = 0.35625$ and $|f(0.35625)|=0.0122024760$. Why aren't the iterations stopped when $|f(0.35)|\le \epsilon=0.02$?

Comment: The stopping criterion is **not** that $|f(x_{\textrm{mid}})|\leq\epsilon$, but that $|x_n-x_{n-1}|\leq\epsilon$, i.e., the absolute difference between the successive approximations should be $\leq\epsilon$. Equivalently, you can state the stopping (convergence) criterion as $|a_n-b_n|\leq\epsilon$ where $[a_n,b_n]$ is the interval on which bisection is performed in the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ iteration.

Comment: When $x_{\textrm{mid}}=0.35$, bisection is being performed on $[0.3,0.4]$ but $|0.3-0.4|=0.1\gt 0.02$. It's only when the iteration reaches to bisection on $[0.35,0.3625]$ that we have $|0.35-0.3625|=0.0125\leq 0.02$ for the first time (the iteration before this is on $[0.35,0.375]$ where $|0.35-0.375|=0.025\gt 0.02$). So, the bisection process terminates on $[0.35,0.3625]$ and we get the final approximation $\dfrac{0.35+0.3625}2=0.35625$

Comment: So why is using |f(xmid)|≤ϵ wrong in the given problem? How do I know when to use another stop criterion?

Comment: Suppose I take a continuous function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ such that $f$ has a root between $2$ and $6$, i.e., $f(2)f(6)\lt 0$ and $f(4)=0.01$. Then, if the tolerance $\epsilon=0.02$, does this necessarily mean that $f$ has a root near $4$ ?

Comment: Why not $|f(x_{mid})|≤ϵ$? Because then the stopping criterion depends on the scale of $f$. The roots and intervals of the bisection method remain the same if you consider $f(x)=1000(2x-e^{-x})$, but the function values change dramatically. In non-bracketing methods you may have to use the function value, but always compare it against epsilon times scale, where the scale might be the value of the original point, $|f(x_n)|≤ϵ\cdot |f(x_0)|$.

Comment: Added screenshot of the notes describing the procedure and its convergence criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error relates to $x$, that is ideally $|x-x_*|\simeq 0.2$ where $x_*$. However, the nature of the problem is that $x_*$ is not known so you have to use information that is available during the computation.

As a bracketing method you know that $x_*\in [a_n,b_n]$ in every step $n$, so that when you use the midpoint $x=c_n=\frac12(a_n+b_n)$, then you know that $$|x_*-c_n|\le r_n=\frac12(b_n-a_n).$$ 
Which means that you can stop when the interval reaches length $0.4$.

```
 n     a[n]      b[n]      c[n]          f(c[n])        r[n]

 0  0.000000  1.600000  0.80000000   1.150671035883  0.80000000
 1  0.000000  0.800000  0.40000000   0.129679953964  0.40000000
 2  0.000000  0.400000  0.20000000  -0.418730753078  0.20000000
 3  0.200000  0.400000  0.30000000  -0.140818220682  0.10000000
 4  0.300000  0.400000  0.35000000  -0.004688089719  0.05000000
 5  0.350000  0.400000  0.37500000   0.062710721209  0.02500000
 6  0.350000  0.375000  0.36250000   0.029065686321  0.01250000
 7  0.350000  0.362500  0.35625000   0.012202476032  0.00625000
 8  0.350000  0.356250  0.35312500   0.003760623283  0.00312500
 9  0.350000  0.353125  0.35156250  -0.000462874346  0.00156250
```

which gives the result as the midpoint of the sixth computed interval, so that $$|x_*-0.3625|\le0.0125<0.02$$

---

That $f$ has, among the evaluated point, the smallest value at $0.35$ only shows that the bisection method is not very "intelligent" and that other methods that also include the function values in the midpoint calculation, like the variants of regula falsi, will be faster.

---

The error in the book probably happened with a table as above that was produced without stopping criterion. Then the function values were compared manually with the error bound from bottom to top to find where the error bound is first violated, which happens from line 7 to line 6 with $c_7=0.35625$, without checking further.

Comment: Added screenshot of the notes.

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is strange. There is no provision for the interval length as a stopping criterion. What if the scale is so large that the numerical values of $f$ jump from $-10$ directly to $+10$? The error probably occurs as the table was produced without stopping criterion as above and then the function values were considered manually from bottom to top to find where the error bound is first violated, which happens from line 7 to line 6 with $c_7=0.35625$.